# Auto-login user to TTY on boot, and then auto-run command within GNU screen

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, auto-login, gnu-screen

Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

**Desired functionality:**
Remote Ubuntu server boots and automatically starts an ongoing process as a specified user. I can then log in remotely at a later time and view the past and current screen output of the ongoing process.

**Current plan:**

Automated steps:

1. User "ubuntu" is logged in automatically to a terminal (TTY) on boot:

   ```
   "sudo nano /etc/init/tty1.conf"

   Change: exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1

   To: exec /sbin/getty --autologin ubuntu -8 38400 tty1
   ```
2. User "ubuntu" runs GNU screen:

   ```
   screen -d -m -S screenname
   ```
3. User "ubuntu" runs the ongoing process within GNU screen:

   ```
   screen -S screenname -p 0 -X stuff "command^M"
   ```

Manual steps at later time:

4. I log in remotely as user "ubuntu" in another terminal (TTY).
5. I re-attach to the GNU screen session started in step 2:

   ```
   screen -r
   ```
6. I am able to view past and current output of the process started in step 3.

**Questions:**

- Is this the most effective way to achieve the desired outcome?
- How can the commands in step 2 & 3 be automated?
- How can the commands in step 2 & 3 *not* activate when I log in manually in step 4?

Comment: Will you be interacting with the attached terminal session, or merely monitoring it? Non-interactive sessions should output to log instead of tty. You can read the log in realtime over ssh.

Comment: In this particulator use case, I will only be monitoring the terminal session output and terminating the process if necessary. However, I would like a solution that works for both monitoring and interacting in real time in case my use case changes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answers** (to my own questions)

- Is this the most effective way to achieve the desired outcome? 
  I am still unsure if the solutions below are the most effective, but I can confirm that it at least works on the stated version on Ubuntu.
- How can the commands in step 2 & 3 be automated?
- How can the commands in step 2 & 3 not activate when I log in manually in step 4? 
   
  **Step one** 
  I put the following at the bottom of the .profile file in the user directory of the user being automatically logged in during step 1 above (/home/ubuntu/.profile):

  ```
  pgrep processname || /home/ubuntu/processscript.sh
  ```

  When the user is automatically logged in, this command will execute automatically because it is in .profile. The first part of the command (before the "||" checks if 'processname' is already running. If not, it will execute the second part of the command (after the "||") i.e. "processscript.sh" ... If 'processname' is already running, it won't.
   
  This check was necessary as the process I wanted to run could not have multiple instances running at the same time. In addition, it solves the problem of process running a second time when I log in manually later.

  **Step two**
   
  Create a shell script file called "processscript.sh" with the following contents:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  screen -d -m -S screenname &&
  screen -S screenname -p 0 -X stuff "/home/ubuntu/command.sh^M"
  ```

  Ensure "processscript.sh" is in the /home/ubuntu directory, and that it is executable with the command:

  ```
  chmod 744 processscript.sh
  ```

  The above shell script creates a screen instance with the name "screenname", and if completed successfully, it stuffs the commandline of that screen instance with the command "command.sh" with a carriage return (which is what the "^M" at the end does).
   
  **Step three** 
  In the previous step, I encountered some problems when stuffing a command with attributes to the screen commandline (I think some character escaping was required). To resolve this simply, I added the full command with attributes to a shell script and used that instead. Therefore, create another shell script (as above) called "command.sh" and add the full command in there.